# Is it a good practice to have multiple relationships between two DB tables?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have two DB tables, **ACTIVITY** and **USER**.

In the **ACTIVITY** table I have 3 fields **AssignedTo**, **CreatedBy** and **LastModifiedBy** that need to be related (1 to many, so that a user can create, modify and be assigned to many activities) with **UserId** field and primary key of the **USER** table.

Is it a good practice to create three different relationships between the two tables, all three connected with the primary key, in this case **UserId**, of the parent table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nothing wrong with that. Just do it, it is correct.

While thinking about it: You might take a look at versioning of records. That is a step further but gives you even more info about who edited a record and when.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have several more fields in my tables to register timestamps and also a log table, I just omitted them to make my question more simple.

Comment: Ok, sounds nice. Any more questions on this issue? It is just accepted standard of building relations in RDBMS's so it shouldn't give you any headaches!